# How Do I Enter Text On The OSX Login Window?

Tags: macos, plugins, authentication, osx-mavericks, sfauthorizationpluginview

I'm trying to make an `osx` app where the password is entered for you after a series of measures. I have seen apps like Knock To Unlock and TockenLock do such a thing and yet I can find any API on the web. I have researched into `SFAuthorizationPluginView` but these apps aren't using it, I checked the place where the plugins are stored and there isn't anything thats not installed by native OSX. I appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks

Comment: They're probably using proprietary daemons started by root that enter the text field's value. You don't find documentation on the web because they want to discourage new developers from doing things like this. When you're skilled enough to do it right, you'll know how and won't need a tutorial.

Comment: Well, how much more skilled do i need to get,been with Obj-C for 5 years...